# Keras ImageDataGenerator : Found 0 images belonging to 70 classes

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am using Google colab with Google drive mounted. I have a folder structure like this -

```
MPEG7_CE-Shape-1_Part_B
    |_shoe
    |_apple
    |_snake
    ...
```

There are 70 folders like *shoe*, *apple*, *snake* and so on, and each has 20 .gif files (binary images).

I used the following code for ImageDataGenerator train and validation split -

```
dataset_path="/content/drive/MyDrive/MPEG7_CE-Shape-1_Part_B"

BATCH_SIZE = 1
def image_data_generator(data_dir,
                       data_augment=False,
                       batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                       target_size=(256, 256),
                       color_mode='grayscale',
                       class_mode='binary',
                       shuffle=True):
  if data_augment:
      datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   rotation_range=20,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   validation_split=0.2,#this is the trick
                                   horizontal_flip=True)
  else:
      datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

  generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(data_dir,
                                          target_size=target_size,
                                          color_mode=color_mode,
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=shuffle,
                                          class_mode=class_mode)
  return generator

train_generator = image_data_generator(dataset_path,data_augment=False)
```

But it is giving the following log on running this code -

```
Found 0 images belonging to 70 classes.
```

Could anyone kindly suggest what may be causing this issue?

Comment: ImageDataGenerator does not support loading images from GIF files.

Comment: But according to https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/, it supports .gif files

Comment: No, not according to the source code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py#L30

Comment: Also I think you confused ImageDataGenerator with image_dataset_from_directory, not  the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

ImageDataGenerator doesn't seem to accept .gif images as mentioned in the comments. I converted all my files to .png files and the same code as mentioned in the question worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

basically this is because keras is looking for images not in the data_dir, but in the folder below. You had to change data_dir to '/content/drive/MyDrive/' or create subfolder '/train' and move your pics there. I don't understand why, but it worked several times in my case